# The function should return an array of the first n multiples of the number x

Tags: javascript, function

```
function multiples(x, n) {
    let m = [];
    for (let i=1; i<= n; i++){
        x *= n[i];
        m.push(x);
    }
    return m;
    }
```

I don't understand why my function is not working. I Need help please.

Comment: There are already multiple answers existing on SO for your query. Please look at the attached question and do some digging

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

```
 function multiples(x, n) {
  let m = [];
  for (let i=1; i<= n; i++){
      m.push(x*i);
  }
  return m;
}
```

The thing you were not achieving your desired output is due to the fact you are treating n as an array which is not. You just need to multiply the number x with i (which should be increasing until it becomes equal to n) and push it to the array.

Comment: The question is a big dupe, it does not help SO in any way

Comment: You can upvote if you feel like this helped.